# GWT shows an empty page

Tags: gwt, runtime-error

From time to time I run into it. E.g., right now I can't see anything in my project but everything is OK in a sandbox project.

I've already found the bug. I used `MapWidget` before calling `loadMapsApi` (see [the guide](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/MapsGettingStarted)). But there might be something less obvious next time. It would be better if a web page gave an error message or some feedback.

What should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I press *Debug As -> Web Application*. It allows me to use breakpoints and debug client code.